# Different results for "first day of previous month"

Tags: php, date

Why I got different result from

```
var_dump(strtotime(date('d.m.Y',strtotime("first day of previous month"))));
```

and

```
var_dump(strtotime("first day of previous month"));
```

result is:
    int(1396303200) and
    int(1396364471)

Comment: the first one is of d.m.Y formatted date and the second one is just a timestamp

Answer (score 2):

using date('d.m.Y') will cut off the hours, minutes and seconds. Thus returning you the timestamp it was at midnight.

If you use strtotime without filtering it through date, it returns the hours, minutes and seconds according to current time. Here in occurence, you ran the script arround 17 hours after midnight.

```
echo date('d.m.Y',strtotime("first day of previous month"));// 1.4.2014
echo date('d.m.Y H:i:s',strtotime("first day of previous month"));// 1.4.2014 17:26
echo date('d.m.Y H:i:s',strtotime("1.4.2014"));// 1.4.2014 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 2):

This has to do with how `strtotime()` interprets your date string.

From the [documentation for `strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime):

> Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas **if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed.** To avoid potential ambiguity, it's best to use ISO 8601 (YYYY-MM-DD) dates or DateTime::createFromFormat() when possible.

Let's see what the timestamp values correspond to:

```
echo date('r', 1396303200) . "\n";
echo date('r', 1396364471);
```

Output:

```
Tue, 01 Apr 2014 03:30:00 +0530
Tue, 01 Apr 2014 20:31:11 +0530
```

See the output of the following `var_dump()` statement:

```
var_dump(date('d.m.Y',strtotime("first day of previous month")));
```

It outputs:

```
string(10) "01.04.2014"
```

Here the separator is a dot, so `strtotime()` will interpret the date as of `DD-MM-YYYY` format.

To avoid such ambiguity, always use [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) instead.

Answer (score 1):

The format of `date()` matters as strtotime will interpret it different depending on that. Stick to standard formats like YYYY-MM-DD and you'll get expected results.

In your case, you use `d.m.Y` which will give you `01.04.2014`. Is that April 1st or January 4th? PHP doesn't know so it guesses in this case. If you used `Y-m-d` you'd get the expected results as that format is not ambiguous to PHP.

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/vtlwOU)

```
var_dump(strtotime("01.04.2014"));
var_dump(strtotime("04.01.2014"));
var_dump(strtotime("2014-04-01"));
int(1396310400) 
int(1388793600) 
int(1396310400)
```